# Generating an MD5 for flute software

Tags: shell, openssl, md5, ubuntu-14.04

Hi I have a software that is called MAD FLUTE, It send files from a server to several clients using multicast,it uses FEC, the problem that I have is that when I want to send a list of files in the form of an FDT_TSI.xml it adds the MD5 of each file for the receiver to check if the file are correct.

Since I'm doing the FDT file with a script I haven't found a way to generate the MD5 like the software
`Content-MD5="c+kuA8jR7esYd1k1PZgVJw=="` even if I use openssl-md5 to generate it

What can I do?

Comment: Content-Location="file:////var/www/mpd/sintel_1200kbit/sintel21.m4s
         Content-Length="131003"
         Content-MD5="e0N+CmyN0D/qlx6w/m7UIQ=="/>

Comment: if I do openssl dgst -md5 -hex sintel21.m4s 
MD5(sintel21.m4s)= 7b437e0a6c8dd03fea971eb0fe6ed421

Comment: You should edit your question with further like that and not add comments (so you can provide useful formatting).

Comment: What is the issue here exactly? Are you unable to generate the correct `MD5` sum? Are you trying to figure out how to generate an output line in that format automatically? Something else?

Comment: Click the `edit` link at the bottom of your question, and use the `{}` formatting tool to paste in that additional information.  Good luck.